# HighCharts: Resize markers of scatter chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am using HighCharts version 4.0.4. I have a scatter chart which has percentage values for width and height. So the graph resizes automatically if the size of the container / the window has changed.

The only thing which does not change in size is the radius of the markers, because it seems that I only can define a Number, see here [plotOptions.scatter.marker.radius](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker.radius).

Here is a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/orv7bbhs/2/) with a fix `radius`of 10.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 10
                }
            }
        }
        /*, ... */
    });
});
```

Resizing the container / window, the marker size is always the same. But my web page uses percentage or `rem` values and I also want to resize all markers of the graph. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `radius` only takes a number, you can hook a handler to the `window.resize` (for example) and use it to grow or shrink the marker radius based on whether the width has increased or decreased (you can change the marker radius programmatically by passing an object with the new radius to the `update` method on each series).

I don't know if that is the path you want to take or not, but I've updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/orv7bbhs/4/) with a simple example showing just that.
In it I increment the marker radius by 1 if the handler detects that the width as increased and decrement it by 1 if it detects a decrease (you will have to figure out a better growth/decrease algorithm.

Comment: Is there another better solution? If the graph is redrawn, the redraw event is fired, right? So maybe this is the right place to change the size of the markers?

Comment: That I do not know. I first tried to use the same logic in the [Redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) event handler, but for some reason the call to the series [update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) always fails with an `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` inside it and I didn't have the time to investigate why.

Comment: When calling `series.update()` it will fire `redraw` event. And when you put `series.update()` in `redraw()` event, you will create infinite loop. That's the reason why not updating chart in redraw event.